# Creating a class implementing an interface

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I created a class and i am adding an interface but in visual studios i noticed that the color of the interface didn't change as if it is not an interface. Even though i am using the same interface in a different class and it is recognized fine. What could be the cause of a class not recognizing an interface?

my class: `public class Teaching:ISchools` and it is not recognizing `ISchools` but in my other class `public class Students:ISchools` - ISchools is recognized.

What should i be looking into for this?

Comment: Does it compile fine?

Comment: Are Teaching and ISchools in the same namespace?

Comment: Is your interface defined as an interface?

Comment: May be you're missing reference/namespace in using

Comment: Right Click on `ISchools` and click on `Resolve`

Comment: @Andrei yes it compiles fine

Comment: @loop852, then I would say you should just forget about it. VS does some weird things with highlighting from time to time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> my class: public class Teaching:ISchools and it is not recognizing
>   ISchools but in my other class public class Students:ISchools -
>   ISchools is recognized.
>
> What should i be looking into for this?

You should verify that you're referencing the relevant Project/Assembly which the required `interface` is defined in and also make to use the correct `namespace` of it.

**To recap, you need to:**

1. Verify that you are referencing to the correct Assembly of the interface.
2. Verify that you are using the correct Namespace of this interface.

In order to check it, right-click on your Project **->** Add Reference... **->** Select the correct assembly and add it.